# How to Trim White Spaces from input field in ant-design form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, antd, trim

I have a form with `ant design`. I want to add a rule for each input field that the user can't enter spaces to fill the input. (spaces forbidden)

I try this method `{ transform: (value) => value.trim() }`but it doesn't work.

I appreciate your help.

```
<>
  <Form.Item
    label={t("forms.inputs.Name.label")}
    rules={[
      {
        required: true,
        message: t("forms.inputs.Name.rules.required"),
      },
      {
        min: 3,
        message: t("forms.inputs.Name.rules.minLength"),
      },
    ]}>
    <Input />
  </Form.Item>

  <Form.Item
    label={t("forms.inputs.job.label")}
    rules={[
      {
        required: true,
        message: t("forms.inputs.job.rules.required"),
      },
    ]}>
    <Input />
  </Form.Item>

  <Form.Item
    label={t("forms.inputs.Company.label")}
    rules={[
      {
        required: true,
        message: t("forms.inputs.Company.rules.required"),
      },
    ]}>
    <Input placeholder={t("forms.inputs.currentCompany.placeholder")} />
  </Form.Item>
</>
```

Comment: Probably you could save the output from `transform` in a `state`, and then get it back inside `getFieldValue` or `validateFields`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write a custom validation [rule](https://ant.design/components/form/#Rule):

```js
<Form.Item
  label="Username"
  name="username"
  rules={[
    {
      required: true,
      message: "Required"
    },
    {
      validator: (_, value) =>
        !value.includes(" ")
          ? Promise.resolve()
          : Promise.reject(new Error("No spaces allowed"))
    }
  ]}
>
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
```

For email validation, you can use the following regex pattern:

```js
<Form.Item
  label="Email"
  name="email"
  rules={[
    {
      required: true,
      message: "Required"
    },
    {
      pattern: /([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|\"([]!#-[^-~ \t]|(\\[\t -~]))+\")@([-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+(\.[-!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~]+)*|\[[\t -Z^-~]*])/,
      message: "Invalid email"
    }
  ]}
  normalize={(value, prevVal, prevVals) => value.trim()}
>
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd-4-22-3-forked-1glcvj?file=/demo.js)

Comment: thank you! it works! but is there a way  like a                                                                                       {
    pattern: REGEX.email,
    message: t('forms.inputs.email.rules.pattern'),
 },                                                                                                                                        (using a pattern for spaces?)

Comment: @Negin Edited my answer with email regex validation

Comment: thank you! but  regex validation is too long. is there another way that formItem or form itself remove the spaces?with out user get any error

Comment: There's a lot of various email regexes that you can use. This is another one I found from emailregex.com if the one I posted in my answer isn't suitable: `/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`

Comment: Um... regex patterns are in general very long. If you want to do post processing of the value after input, you can refer to the other answers posted here.

Comment: @Negin So I just modified my answer again. You can use `normalize` on the `Form.Item` to trim the value.

Comment: thank you so much! it is great but there is a problem when i enter the space it automatically remove space(it is OK) but error for other rule shows(fg:name must have three character) i want to do this without any error (just remove space without show other error)

Comment: Not sure what this `three character` error you're referring to. It sounds like we're getting out of scope from your original question.

Comment: thanks for your help my question is how to remove spaces without any error?when i use ```normalize``` it remove spaces automatically but shows error message for first rule for example enter your full name

Comment: using this rule, I can't enter space. it's bad

Answer (score 2):

Just set the ***whitespace*** property to ***true*** in the rule like so. ([Reference](https://ant.design/components/form#rule))

```
{
    required: true,
    whitespace: true,
    message: "Required"
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. How come I'm the first to upvote it? xD

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trimming onChange, do that in an onBlur callback:
`formatInput = (event) => { const attribute = event.target.getAttribute('name') this.setState({ [attribute]: event.target.value.trim() }) }`

or when you click enter
`onKeyPress={(e) => {if (e.key === "Enter") {setValue(e.target.value.trim())} }}`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this instead of using `trim()`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Form, Input } from 'antd';


const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setValue] = useState({input1: '', input2: '', input3: ''});
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log('Success:', values);
  };

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
  };

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    let {value} = e.target;
    let data = {...inputValue};
    if (value.length && value[0] === ' ') {
      data[e.target.name] = '';
      setValue(data);
      return;
    }
    data[e.target.name] = value;
    setValue(data);
  }

  return (
    <Form
      name="basic"
      labelCol={{
        span: 8,
      }}
      wrapperCol={{
        span: 16,
      }}
      initialValues={{
        remember: true,
      }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <>
        <Form.Item
          label={t("forms.inputs.Name.label")}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: t("forms.inputs.Name.rules.required"),
            },
            {
              min: 3,
              message: t("forms.inputs.Name.rules.minLength"),
            },
          ]}>
          <Input name="input1" value={inputValue.input1} onChange={handleOnChange} />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          label={t("forms.inputs.job.label")}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: t("forms.inputs.job.rules.required"),
            },
          ]}>
          <Input name="input2" value={inputValue.input2} onChange={handleOnChange} />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          label={t("forms.inputs.Company.label")}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: t("forms.inputs.Company.rules.required"),
            },
          ]}>
          <Input name="input3" value={inputValue.input3} onChange={handleOnChange} placeholder={t("forms.inputs.currentCompany.placeholder")} />
        </Form.Item>
      </>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Item
                      initialValue={dto.debtorData?.iin}
                      label={i18n.t('iinBinSearch')}
                      name="debtorIin"
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          transform: (value) => value.trim(),
                          message: i18n.t('formik.validate.required'),
                        },
                        {
                          len: 12,
                          message: i18n.t('error.iinBin.length '),
                          transform: (value) => value.trim(),
                        },
                        {
                          pattern: regex_patterns.ONLY_NUMBERS,
                          message: i18n.t('textKk.must-not-be-text'),
                        },
                      ]}
                    >
                      <Search name="debtorIin" onSearch={this.onDebtorSearch} />
                    </Item>
```

You need to pass trim func in rule object - this is works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **whitespace** rule in the Form Item that is wrapping your Input.

```
<Form.Item
  rules={[
    {required: true, whitespace: true, message: "This field is required"}
  ]}
>
```

docs: https://ant.design/components/form#rule

> Failed if only has whitespace, only work with type: 'string'
> rule. boolean

---

Alternatively, **if your field is not required**, you can use the **normalize** prop to transform the value of your input by removing the spaces before and after the text.

```
<Form.Item
  normalize={(value) => value.trim()}
>
```

docs: https://ant.design/components/form#formitem

> Normalize value from component value before passing to Form instance.
> Do not support async. (value, prevValue, prevValues) => any